# Do I need to do something different to mount blinds on a sloped ceiling?

Tags: blinds

I am updating my blinds and have come across a situation where the ceiling slopes towards the window. The previous installation used metal clips to secure the blinds, which I was told need to maintain a right angle to the wall to prevent the mechanism from catching and potentially failing over time. I am contemplating using a wooden plank as the mounting surface for the new blinds but am unsure if this approach is feasible given the sloping wall.

1. Are the specific metal clips used previously essential for ensuring the longevity and proper function of the blinds, and do they have a recognised name or type I should refer to when searching for compatibility with new blinds?
2. If mounting onto the wooden plank is not recommended, could you suggest alternative methods or hardware that would suit the installation of blinds in this scenario?

[image]

[image]

Comment: What, exactly, is the issue you're running into? The way the ceiling is sloped, it looks like the head rail (the part that mounts into the clips) will be angled, however, gravity will ensure the rest of the blinds hand vertically. You were "told" that they need to maintain a right angle to the wall, but have you actually tried the new blinds to see if they'll work? If not, a beveled piece of wood, screwed to the ceiling and providing a horizontal surface to attache the new blinds to should work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Mounting clips are common to the blinds they are used to hold. There is no "type" per say.  Any blinds you purchase should come with the mounting clips needed for those blinds.

As for the "wood plank", most any mounting clip can be screwed into wood. Will it work in your situation I cannot say, as you did not include the details as to where the plank would be.

Comment: Thanks. I was referring to the existing wooden plank which is attached to the wall. About 5cm from wall as seen in pictures. Thanks

Comment: @tedioustortoise the plank looks attached to the ceiling

Comment: exactly, the wood in the picture is on the ceiling...unless your pic is turned 90 deg.  Remember any mounting clip can be screwed into wood.